# Client-side logging for Atlasboard

Tags: logging, client-side, dashboard, atlasboard

I'm trying to debug a new Atlasboard widget, but I can't figure out how to log from it.

I tried creating a logger and using `logger.info(...)` but nothing shows up in the console or the Atlasboard client log. How do I write to the Atlasboard client log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` does work, the problem was a syntax error in my widget that wasn't detected by the editor I was using.

If not even the widget title is showing on your dashboard, you've likely got a syntax error in your widget.